# .empty() .append() setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to loop through several more divs, but cannot find the correct syntax. It works with just the two divs. I have tried *var src = state ? '#div1' : #div2 : '#div3' ;* 
I am inexperienced in script. Can somebody please show me the correct way to incorporate more divs? Many thanks for any advice.

```
(function () {
    var delay = 5000;
    var state = 0;
    (function next() {
        state = 1 - state;
        var src = state ? '#div1' : '#div2' ;
        var $contents = $(src).contents().clone().fadeIn(1999);
        $('#indexscroll').empty().append($contents);
        setTimeout(next, delay);
    })();
})();
```

Comment: a jsFiddle would be realy Helpful !

Comment: What is this code attempting to do? I linted it into a jsbin and immediately realized that it's doing dome loops and repeated animations. Hoever, it uses a setTime out when animations can be managed with jQuery and $.Deferred objects. So that leaves the question what is the expected outcome (specs)?

Comment: `state ? '#div1' : '#div2' ;` is a shorthand and works for only two results, you can  put #div1,#div2 and #div3 into array and loop over it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a list of `divs`, increment `state` as you go, and reset it to 0 when it runs off the end of the list:

```
var delay = 5000;
var state = 0;
var myDivs = ['#div1', '#div2', '#div3' /* etc. */ ];

(function next() {
  if (state >= myDivs.length)
    state = 0;

  var src = myDivs[state++];

  var $contents = $(src).contents().clone().fadeIn(1999);
  $('#indexscroll').empty().append($contents);
  setTimeout(next, delay);
})();
```

Comment: Thank you, Paul! Your suggestion worked perfectly for what I was wanting to do.  Best regards!